# R- Using pointers in memoise arguments

Tags: r, pointers, reference, bigdata, memoization

I am a newbie in R and need help figure out this problem.
I have a training set (`bigData`) in which I have to look for neighbors of some test data (`searchDat`). I am trying to use `memoise` to keep track of the instances already being searched. My problem is that if I send arguments in my search function `searchNeigh(bigData,seachDat[i])` each time for some i's, `bigData` is being cached in `memoise` on every call, and that is occupying a lot of memory. 
Is there anyway I can just send a reference/pointer to `bigData` into the memoised function instead of the whole dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about details of memoise, but there are no pointers in `R`.

Comment: memoise is used to memorize a function call. It caches the input arguments and the resulting output. So if a function is called again with the same arguments, memoise returns the values computed in the previous call, which saves unnecessary and repeated computations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply RHertel. That means I'll have to look for some other way of saving on repeated search. I was trying not to use a global variable. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful. I wish you good luck and much success with your project.

Comment: But thanks anyway. I solved my problem by using 'Rcpp' and 'inline' packages, wherein I could write a block of 'c++' code within an R code. I didnt use 'memoise' though. That will still be interesting to know.